# c# include an image that changes accordingly to a number

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a c# GUI project where a prompt asks for height(inches) and weight(lbs) and when you press the calculate button a window pops up stating your BMI and body type (under weight/overweight etc.). I am trying to code a picture underneath the text according to the bmi but I cant figure out how to get a picture to appear and change according to the bmi.

```
namespace p1s4_BMI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CalculateButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(HeightTextBox.Text, out double heightInches))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid height.");
                return;
            }
            if (!double.TryParse(WeightTextBox.Text, out double weightPounds))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid weight.");
                return;
            }

            double calculatedBMI = (weightPounds * 703) / (heightInches * heightInches);

            double bmi = Math.Round(calculatedBMI, 1);

            string bmiCategory;
            if (bmi < 18.5)
            {
                bmiCategory = "Underweight";
            }
            else if (bmi < 25)
            {
                bmiCategory = "Healthy weight";
            }
            else if (bmi < 30)
            {
                bmiCategory = "Overweight";
            }
            else
            {
                bmiCategory = "Obesity";
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"Your BMI is: {bmi}\nBMI Category: {bmiCategory}");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to create a string for the image and set it to the picture name in the if and else statements and entered the code below but it didn't work.

```
using (var messageForm = new Form())
{
    messageForm.Text = "BMI Image";
    messageForm.Size = new Size(300, 300); // Adjust size as needed

    var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile($"{imageName}.jpg");

    messageForm.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

    messageForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "did not work" tells us little. What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: where is `imageName` declared?

Comment: Is there any update? Can you provide more information about your code and the place to use the second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, after the `Calculationbutton_click` event you want the result and the corresponding image to be displayed in a popup window. If I stick to the code above, I would add a `Label` to the `messageForm` instead of the `MessageBox`.

Try this instead of the `MessageBox` line:

```cs
using (var messageForm = new Form())
{
    messageForm.Text = "BMI Image";
    messageForm.Size = new Size(300, 300); // Adjust size as needed
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = $"Your BMI is: {bmi}\nBMI Category: {bmiCategory}";
    label.Top=messageForm.Top;
    label.AutoSize  = true;
    var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox.Top = label.Bottom + 20;
    //Opcional picutre box properties
    pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile($"{bmiCategory}.jpg");
    messageForm.Controls.Add(label);
    messageForm.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

    messageForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Properties of the label and picturebox can of course be customized. Furthermore, you need to add to the project the 4 images named according to `bmiCategory`. You need to copy these pictures to the folder of the repo near the `.exe` file (usually in the case of Visual Studio: `Bin` -> `Debug`).